# Nightwatch js Using page objects as variable in all steps

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing, pageobjects

I have some page object document with code:

```
var gmailItemClicks = {
    composeClick: function () {
        return this.section.leftToolbarSection.click('@compose');
    }
};
module.exports = {
    commands: [gmailItemClicks],
    sections: {
        leftToolbarSection: {
            selector: '.nH.oy8Mbf.nn.aeN',
            elements: {
                compose: { selector: '.T-I.J-J5-Ji.T-I-KE.L3' },
            }
        },
};
```

and the test file with many steps, like this:

```
module.exports = {    
    '1st step': function (client) {
        gmail.composeClick();
    },
    '2d step': function (client) {
        gmail.composeClick();
    }
}
```

i can use 'gmail' variable if it is in every step like this:

```
module.exports = {    
    '1st step': function (client) {
        var gmail = client.page.gmail();
        gmail.composeClick();
    },
    '2d step': function (client) {
        var gmail = client.page.gmail();
        gmail.composeClick();
    }
}
```

but i want to separate this var from the test code in the steps. I tried to use

```
const gmail = require('./../pages/gmail');
```

in the test before module.exports bloсk, and i tried to use globals.js file with the same syntax, but i get the error " ✖ TypeError: gmail.composeClick is not a function".
Now i have just one big function where are all steps used variable declared once inside the func, but the log of test looks ugly, i cant to see when the one step started and where it was stopped.
What i missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create the object in the before block. Here is how it would look like in my code:

```
(function gmailSpec() {
  let gmailPage;
  function before(client) {
    gmailPage = client.page.gmail();
    gmailPage.navigate()
  }
  function after(client) {
    client.end();
  }

  function firstStep() {
    gmailPage.composeClick()
  }

  function secondStep() {
    gmailPage.composeClick()
  }

  module.exports = {
    before,
    after,
    '1st step': firstStep,
    '2nd step': secondStep
  }
}());
```

Hope that helps you :)

Comment: Yes, it helps me. Thank you!